# Different initialization, Common Lisp

Tags: class, lisp, common-lisp

Can I mimic different constructors in CL?

To elaborate -- in, say, C++, I can make different constructors for the same class depending on what arguments are passed.

Can I do this with CLOS? Probably having different `initialize-instance`s key args or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to doing this is to have a secondary initialization method:

```
(defclass myclass ()
  ((s1 :initarg :s1 :accessor s1)))

(defgeneric initialize-myclass (dispatch class &key))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((c myclass) &rest args &key (dispatch 'normal)
                                       &allow-other-keys)
  (apply #'initialize-myclass dispatch c args))

(defmethod initialize-myclass ((dispatch (eql 'normal)) (class myclass) &key))

(defmethod initialize-myclass ((dispatch (eql 'special)) (class myclass)
                               &key x &allow-other-keys)
  (print x))
```

Now you can say

```
(make-instance 'myclass :dispatch 'special ...)
```

For instance.  Note this is not necessarily a good way of doing it, but it does work, and I've used it.  Note also I may have got the keyword-argument defaulting wrong: I never remember where you need to say `&allow-other-keys` & where you don't, and where the *right* place to say it is.

The basic problem here is that we want an additional thing to dispatch on: `initialize-instance` can dispatch on the class of the object being defined, but that's *all* it can dispatch on.  In particular it can't dispatch on one of its keyword arguments because you can't do that in CLOS.  But we can take one of its keyword arguments (`dispatch` here) and 'bless' it as a positional argument to a secondary initialization generic function, which then *can* dispatch on that argument.

Comment: Oh, it's like, making another method that would be called before initialize-instance?

Comment: @AndrewS. Well, it's called by the after method on `initialize-instance` so it runs, really, after it.  I've added what I hope is a better description.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `initialize-instance` is typically defined as an `:after` method to run some sort of post-processing once the instance has been initialized through `make-instance`. What you might do is use parametric polymorphism (dispatching on parameters) and have different methods initialize your instance based on the parameters supplied. Consider the following example:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defclass my-class ()
       ((a :initarg :a
           :accessor my-class-a)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::MY-CLASS>
CL-USER> (defmethod make-my-class ((a number))
       (make-instance 'my-class :a (format nil "Look ma, a number ~a" a)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD COMMON-LISP-USER::MAKE-MY-CLASS (NUMBER) {1016445273}>
CL-USER> (defmethod make-my-class ((a string))
       (make-instance 'my-class :a (format nil "Look ma, a string ~a" a)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD COMMON-LISP-USER::MAKE-MY-CLASS (STRING) {10166065C3}>
CL-USER> (make-my-class 10)
#<MY-CLASS {1016690E33}>
CL-USER> (my-class-a *)
"Look ma, a number 10"
CL-USER> (make-my-class "foo")
#<MY-CLASS {1016694CD3}>
CL-USER> (my-class-a *)
"Look ma, a string foo"
```

As you can see, the method `make-my-class` dispatches on its argument and initializes `my-class` accordingly.